# MySQL - Max() return wrong result

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I tried this query on MySQL server (5.1.41)...

```
SELECT max(volume), dateofclose, symbol, volume, close, market FROM daily group by market
```

I got this result:

```
max(volume) dateofclose symbol  volume  close   market
287031500     2010-07-20  AA.P    500     66.41   AMEX
242233000     2010-07-20  AACC    16200   3.98    NASDAQ
1073538000   2010-07-20  A       4361000 27.52   NYSE
2147483647   2010-07-20  AAAE.OB 400     0.01    OTCBB
437462400     2010-07-20  AAB.TO  31400   0.37    TSX
61106320       2010-07-20  AA.V    0       0.24    TSXV
```

As you can see, the maximum volume is VERY different from the 'real' value of the volume column?!?

The volume column is define as int(11) and I got 2 million rows in this table but it's very far from the max of MyISAM storage so I cannot believed this is the problem!? What is also strange is data get show from the same date (dateofclose). If I force a specific date with a WHERE clause, the same symbol came out with different max(volume) result. This is pretty weird...

Need some help here!

UPDATE :

Here's my edited "working" request:

```
SELECT a.* FROM daily a 
INNER JOIN ( 
SELECT market, MAX(volume) AS max_volume 
FROM daily 
WHERE dateofclose = '20101108' 
GROUP BY market 
) b ON 
a.market = b.market AND 
a.volume = b.max_volume
```

So this give me, by market, the highest volume's stock (for nov 8, 2010).

Comment: What do you mean by "real" value?  The MAX is returning the highest volume value per market value.

Comment: Yes but the corresponding column doesn't seem to match. Adding the volume column to select show this.

Comment: It seems like a bug that MySql doesn't error if you SELECT columns that are not in the GROUP BY.  (SQL Server will throw an error.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As you can see, the maximum volume is VERY different from the 'real' value of the volume column?!?

This is because MySQL rather bizarrely doesn't `GROUP` things in a sensical way.

Selecting `MAX(column)` will get you the maximum value for that column, but selecting other columns (or `column` itself) will **not necessarily** select the entire row that the found `MAX()` value is in. You essentially get an arbitrary (and usually useless) row back.

Here's a thread with some workarounds using subqueries:
[How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Comment: That does the trick! I applied the recipe and this is my resulting query: SELECT tt.* from daily tt inner join ( select dateofclose, symbol, volume, close, market, MAX(volume) as MaxVolume FROM daily group by market) groupedtt on tt.market = groupedtt.market AND tt.volume = groupedtt.MaxVolume

Answer (score 2):

This is a subset of the "greatest n per group" problem.  (There is a tag with that name but I am a new user so I can't retag).

This is usually best handled with an analytic function, but can also be written with a join to a sub-query using the same table.  In the sub-query you identify the max value, then join to the original table on the keys to find the row that matches the max.

Assuming that {dateofclose, symbol, market} is the grain at which you want the maximum volume, try:

```
select
    a.*, b.max_volume
from daily a
join
(
    select
        dateofclose, symbol, market, max(volume) as max_volume
    from daily
    group by
        dateofclose, symbol, market
) b
on
    a.dateofclose = b.dateofclose
    and a.symbol = b.symbol
    and a.market = b.market
```

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/sql-fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column) for reference.

Comment: Humm, this doesn't work. After 30 sec of thinking, it return exactly the same number of results as there is row in this table! I clean up my request and it look like this : SELECT a.* FROM daily a INNER JOIN ( SELECT market, MAX(volume) AS max_volume FROM daily WHERE dateofclose = '20101108' GROUP BY market ) b ON a.market = b.market AND a.volume = b.max_volume

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adjusting your query to include Symbol in the grouping?

```
    SELECT max(volume), dateofclose, symbol, 
   volume, close, market FROM daily group by market, symbol
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I got 24 963 result with still max(volume) different from the volume column. :-(