# "longest film rental duration and the customer who rented the said film" MySQL Sakila query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying write a query that would return the longest film rental duration and the customer who rented the said film (and also the title of the film) in the Sakila database.

As a first step, I've wrote the following query, which is supposed to return the film_id, inventory_id, customer_id and the **longest** duration of rental (in weeks):

```
SELECT DDIFF.*

FROM (SELECT rental.inventory_id, rental.customer_id, DATEDIFF(rental.return_date, rental.rental_date)/7 AS TM FROM rental) AS DDIFF

INNER JOIN  (SELECT  DDIFF.inventory_id, DDIFF.customer_id, MAX(DDIFF.TM) AS WEEKS 
FROM (SELECT  rental.inventory_id, rental.customer_id, DATEDIFF(rental.return_date, rental.rental_date)/7 AS TM FROM rental) AS DDIFF
GROUP BY DDIFF.inventory_id, DDIFF.customer_id) AS MXLST 

ON  DDIFF.TM = MXLST.WEEKS AND  MXLST.inventory_id = DDIFF.inventory_id AND MXLST.customer_id = DDIFF.customer_id

;
```

yet I'm getting some unexpected results (it should return **multiple** rows with the longest duration being 1.4286 weeks, but I'm getting 1.0 weeks for some reason). What am I doing wrong? I'd be very thankful to hear an explanation.

Note that I've tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129983/mysql-max-return-wrong-result) to properly use MAX() yet it still doesn't return the correct results.

Edit: Sakila tables` structure can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure-tables.html)

Comment: Please add your tables' structure

Comment: @juergend done, see my edit.

Comment: Your SQL is more advanced than my minds eye, so I am speculating the cause as 1) the result is rounded to the nearest integer or 2) the result is written to a column/variable that expects integers only.

Comment: @fiprojects I don't think that's the case, since I found names people who were in the results list which weren't supposed to be there. Thanks for your input nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is highly inefficient: you are performing 3 `SELECT`s on full tables and then other operations. I tested your query: it's been running for more than 60 seconds without giving any result. Just killed it and rewrote your query as follows:

```
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, f.title, DATEDIFF(r.return_date,r.rental_date)/7 AS rental_time 
FROM rental AS r
INNER JOIN inventory AS i 
ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
INNER JOIN film AS f
ON i.film_id = f.film_id
INNER JOIN customer AS c
ON r.customer_id = c.customer_id
HAVING rental_time = (SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(return_date,rental_date))/7 FROM rental)
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't interpreted your question correctly. You want to calculate what's the maximum rental time in weeks and then select every rental with such a time?

Comment: I wanna return the full name of the people who rented a film for the longest amount of time in weeks, the title of the film they rented, and the amount of time they rented it for (in weeks - which happens to be 1.4286 weeks for all these people).

Comment: Update: figured it out myself and posted an answer. Thank you for trying at least :)

Comment: Very nice answer! Much more readable than what I posted! Upvoted and selected it as best answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I've managed to solve my own question. Here's an updated query for future reference:

```
SELECT customer.first_name,
       customer.last_name,
       film.title,
       DDIFF.TM AS 'rental duration'
FROM customer,
     film,
     (SELECT inventory.film_id,
             rental.inventory_id,
             rental.customer_id,
             DATEDIFF(rental.return_date, rental.rental_date)/7 AS TM
      FROM rental,
           inventory
      WHERE rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id) AS DDIFF

INNER JOIN (SELECT DDIFF.film_id,
              DDIFF.inventory_id,
              DDIFF.customer_id,
              MAX(DDIFF.TM) AS WEEKS 
            FROM (SELECT inventory.film_id,
                         rental.inventory_id,
                         rental.customer_id,
                         DATEDIFF(rental.return_date, rental.rental_date)/7 AS TM
                  FROM rental,
                       inventory
                  WHERE rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id) AS DDIFF
            GROUP BY DDIFF.film_id,
                     DDIFF.inventory_id,
                     DDIFF.customer_id) AS MXLST 
ON  DDIFF.TM = (SELECT MAX(DDIFF.TM)
                FROM (SELECT inventory.film_id,
                             rental.inventory_id,
                             rental.customer_id,
                             DATEDIFF(rental.return_date, rental.rental_date)/7 AS TM
                      FROM rental,
                           inventory
                      WHERE rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id) AS DDIFF)
AND MXLST.film_id = DDIFF.film_id
AND MXLST.inventory_id = DDIFF.inventory_id
AND MXLST.customer_id = DDIFF.customer_id

WHERE customer.customer_id = DDIFF.customer_id
AND film.film_id = DDIFF.film_id;
```

I admit, it's not efficient nor looks decent, but it's a correct answer. Anyone is welcome to try and find a much more efficient/readable query that returns the same result. Anyway, thanks to everyone who tried to help.